# Connecting to an sftp server with lftp in a passwordless fashion?

Tags: command-line-interface, lftp

I'm running the following script that uses lftp:

```
lftp -f "
open sftp://myuser@sftp_server:443
lcd $FTP_FOLDER
mirror --no-empty-dirs  --only-newer --verbose $FTP_FOLDER $LOCAL_FOLDER
bye
"
```

Now If I've already passed my public key to the server administrator so if do this in the command line:

```
sftp -P 443 myuser@sftp_server
```

I get connected and I get the sftp prompt. When I do this the pwd command tells me that the folder that I need to sync has the path "/0Datos" and that is the value of $FTP_FOLDER.

When I execute the script I get this:

```
    source: Is a directory
    Password:
```

Is there any way to connect without the server asking me for a password (I don't have it) in order to sync the folder 0Datos to a local folder of mine?

Answer (score 2):

Just supply an empty password in the URL:

```
open sftp://myuser:@sftp_server:443
```

lftp asks for the password before connecting to the server, but if the server does not require one lftp does not send it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a colon after your username (myuser:@ instead myuser@)

```
sftp://myuser:@sftp_server:443
```

This will mean no password (empty password).

Comment: This is also required if you have set up an ssh key pair for remote login and you don't want to enter the password for your lftp sftp session.